# Bootstrap: How do i make an h4 resize to fill the width of the columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I need for the heading to change its font size so that it always fills the width of it's columns, or more specifically, to always be as wide as the image above it.

I guess I could use a fixed width image but then it wouldn't be responsive I suppose?

Comment: You could use some JavaScript to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you tried this before? http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: You may be able to to use a combination of css justified text and fitText.js or equivalent script.

Comment: FitText.js is around I believe